# Distributed Transactions in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

As part of a transaction I’m modifying rows in tables via a server link, so have to specify “SET XACT_ABORT ON” in my sproc otherwise it won’t execute. Now I’m noticing that SCOPE_IDENTITY() is returning NULL, which is presumably something to do with the distributed transaction scope?

Does anyone know why and how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [@@IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx):

> The scope of the @@IDENTITY function
>   is current session on the local server
>   on which it is executed. This function
>   cannot be applied to remote or linked
>   servers. To obtain an identity value
>   on a different server, execute a
>   stored procedure on that remote or
>   linked server and have that stored
>   procedure (which is executing in the
>   context of the remote or linked
>   server) gather the identity value and
>   return it to the calling connection on
>   the local server.

And note that although it talks about IDENT_CURRENT and SCOPE_IDENTITY in surrounding paragraphs, they make no appearance in this paragraph; i.e. none of them will work to retrieve identity values from remote servers.